# Update app engine entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How to update existing record in app engine.

Comment: You made comments below that imply you have some code that is not working like you want.  If you include that code here we can more easily help you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

<strike>Use [gql](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) if you have access to the datastore.</strike>
You have to define methods to do the update according your db class. The updates can happen only via the class and it needs to be called upon by requests.

Comment: GQL is a language for doing SELECT queries.  It is completely incapable of updating entities.

Comment: @Wooble - Yes, you are right. I had forgotten about it. For doing an update, you might be defining the methods for the class which inherit from db and do the update accordingly. (@user60448 - search SO for How to delete entities in GAE).

Answer (score 41):

As long as an entity has a key defined it will be updated on `put()`:

```
record = Record(value='foo')
# This creates a new record
record.put()

record.value = 'shmoo'
# This updates it
record.put()

key = record.key()
record2 = Record.get(key)
record2.value = 'bar'
# Yet again this updates the same record
record2.put()
```

Comment: cannot believe this was not picked as the answer...hey everybody, this is the correct answer :O Thanks Michal.

Answer (score 2):

I use GQL to query a find the Entity and if exists update de atribute.

```
 result = db.GqlQuery('select name from Person where name = "tadeu"')
 if result:
   for r in result:
       r.attribute = "value"
       r.put()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the very good overview [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html)?

1. Get the record from the datastore by a query of some kind.
2. Make the changes you need to make
3. Call `put()` on the entity or entities that you changed to save them back to the datastore.