# update an entity in datastore app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update app engine entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066357/update-app-engine-entity)

I need to update entity that I loaded from the datastore. But how?

Comment: You need to add more detail to your questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you go

```
myKey = db.Key.from_path('MyModel', 'mykeyvalue')
rec = db.get(myKey)

rec.MyProperty = 'this is a new value'
rec.put()
```

Here is a link to the documentation.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html